# How to ignore FIND errors in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm using a script to cleanup logfiles from a tomcat webserver.

Problem:

`find $file_pattern` will return an error if a filepattern did not match any results.

The following is run by crontab:

```
arch_logs() {
    for file_pattern; do
        i=1
        for log_file in $(find $file_pattern | sort -r); do
            test $i -eq 1 && ((i=i+1)) && continue;
            sudo gzip "$log_file"
            sudo mv *.gz ./archive/
        done
    done
}

arch_logs 'catalina.2*' 'host-manager.*' 'localhost.*' 'localhost_access_log.*' 'manager.*'
```

https://yottabrain.org/tomcat/tomcat-log-backup/

Result: `find: ‘catalina.2*’: No such file or directory`

Question: how can I prevent those errors from `find` inside the function?

Comment: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: BTW: Aren't you reinventing [`logrotate(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)?